# How to re-position SimpleDialog2?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have [SimpleDialog2](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/index.html) and I show and hide some Content,
I want to re-position the Dialog after hide some data,
How to do this?

Comment: The [documentation](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/options.html) shows a `top` and `left` property, which I would try setting.

Comment: Did you read any of the documentation I linked? Users here are not going to write code for you.

Comment: Ok, I already read the documentation , because I post the link. Also I make a solution.

Comment: @AhmedAssaf any way to resize a dialogue ?

Comment: @sij What do you want with resize? I want more details with the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution , by fire resize event for window, this will make re-position for SimpleDialog2.

Here are the code:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false,window,0);
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/9hsBA/